# triggering mui datagrid export csv from a button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-datatable

I am using **@mui/x-data-grid** and it has the functionality to export table data to CSV with  `<GridToolbarExport />` which works well, now I was wondering if is there a way to trigger this export functionality from another button like the "download" button as I showed in below screenshot [image]

I am aware with some CSS i can move the mui/datagrid export button to top and even change its apearange but my download button has many different functionalities like it changes its visibility, content, and color based on many different parameters so triggering the mui export from this button is my best bet.

right now i am using package `react-csv` which gives me full control over from where and on what component I want to give export functionality but was thinking if can achieve this with mui so I  don't have to use one extra library

I would appreciate your help to solve my problems

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with community license.

For pro and premium licenses, looks like it can be achieved using `apiRef`

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/export/#apiref

Comment: thanks, I could not find any code example or implementation guide for apiRef in mui documentation, if you have used it before can you give one code example for exportDataAsCsv()

Comment: Sorry, I too use the community DataGrid and have the exact same requirement. Just like you, went with react-csv. I used CSVLink to get the solution done.